# AFNetworking 2.0 - How to pass response to another class on success

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am wondering how can I call AFHTTPSessionManagern from different class. Currently I use this code to get the response but I am not sure how to convert this to singleton class which requires parameters and postback link. I am receiving and processing JSON code only.

```
static NSString * const BaseURLString = @"http://www.example.com/";
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:BaseURLString];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{ @"Token" : @"123456"};

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

[manager GET:@"/list-21.aspx?" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    self.someDictionary = responseObject[@"User"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Films"
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Delegation approach.

Create a separate class (Sync.h and Sync.m) which only contains above code of creating AFHTTPSessionManager, Parameters and starting the connection. Create delegate method in this class.
Now from your other class(mainController), create a object of above class and sync.delegate = self.
Once you receive repsonse/error. Delegate to the defined methods which are implemented in mainController.

Below is the example:
SyncManager.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol SyncDelegate<NSObject>

-(void)syncSuccess:(id) responseObject;
-(void)syncFailure:(NSError*) error;

@end

@interface SyncManager: UIViewController
{
}

-(void) serviceCall:(NSString*)url withParams:(NSDictionary*) params;
@end
```

SyncManager.m

```
@interface SyncManager ()

@end

@implementation SyncManager 

-(void) serviceCall:(NSString*)url withParams:(NSDictionary*) params {
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
    [manager GET:@"/list-21.aspx?" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id      responseObject) {
        [self.delegate syncSuccess:responseObject];
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        [self.delegate syncFailure:error];
    }];
}
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
-(void)fetchdata {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"name":@"Arun"};
    SyncManager *sync = [[SyncManager alloc] init];
    sync.delegate = self;
    [sync serviceCall:@"www.google.com" withparams:dictionary]; 
}

-(void)syncSuccess:(id) responseObject {
    // Parse your data
}

-(void)syncFailure:(NSError*) error {
    //display Error
}
```

Comment: Gu thanks for the answer, can you give me some example of the delegate. Also can I put all the api calls for AFNetworking, so I may have more than one method?

Comment: added an example above

Comment: Hi thanks, for example. I tried that but i get error on the line self.delgate saying that property delegate is not found on the object type of SyncManager

Comment: Missed one thing. You need import the delegate in viewControllerClass as well. Below is the line for the same.                                In ViewController.h file, at the below line add your delegate in <> brackets                                                    @interface ViewController: UIViewController<SyncDelegate>

Comment: @ArunGupta  i m getting error that property 'delegate' not found on object type SyncManager in this line in Sync Manager.m --> [self.delegate syncSuccess:responseObject]; 
Please suggest me

Comment: Can you show us your code both syncManager class and vieecontroller from where you are calling it.

Comment: @ArunGupta i tried same as u told me in ur answer but getting error.Please tell me how could i use delegate method in afnetworking based class

Comment: @ArunGupta could you please reply me. where i m doing mistake

Comment: Got the problem. Please add below line just before the getJsonData method                                                                    @property(nonatomic,weak) id <SyncDelegate> delegate;                              Sorry i too missed that in my example :(

Comment: Let me know if are struck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSNotificationCenter and pass the response via that. This has the added bonus that multiple classes can be listening at the same time. If the data affects UI, it gives them the opportunity to update accordingly.

```
[manager GET:@"/list-21.aspx?" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    self.someDictionary = responseObject[@"User"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"USER_DATA_ARRIVED" object:responseObject[@"User"]];

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"USER_DATA_ARRIVED" object:nil];

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Films"
                                                    message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}];
```

Add an observer for the notification name, and the data will be contained in `notification.object`, which if it failed would be nil

Comment: Ok that's makes sense, although most of data will not change so fast to require instant change/reload. My question was more in line of creating singleton class where I can keep all API calls and use them in any controller class.

Comment: Then maybe that was the question you should of asked ;) This approach could still be used in a Singleton, which is how I use them. My ViewControllers add observers for any of the calls its interested in

Comment: I did and no one answered the question so I rephrased it