# iOS: pass data to another class

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, block, delegation

I have my class named "Service" where inside I do a lot of GET/POST request with Alamofire, an example of request id this

```
func requestDocuments(){

        request(.POST, "http://example.com/json/docs")
            .responseJSON { (_, _, JSON, error) in

                if error == nil{

                    var response = JSON as NSArray
                    println("array document: \(response)")


                    //**** HERE I WANT PASS VALUE TO MY VIEW CONTROLLER
                }
                else{

                }
        }
    }
```

and from my viewcontroller:

```
    let service = Service.sharedInstance

    service.requestDocuments()
```

What can I use? delegate method? or what? 
what is the best solution in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func requestDocuments(completion:(data:NSArray?)){

        request(.POST, "http://example.com/json/docs")
            .responseJSON { (_, _, JSON, error) in

                if error == nil{

                    var response = JSON as NSArray
                    println("array document: \(response)")


                    //**** HERE I WANT PASS VALUE TO MY VIEW CONTROLLER

                    completion(data:response)
                }
                else{
                   completion(data:nil)
                }
        }
    }



 var reqDoc = requestDocuments(){ (data) -> Void in 
      if let _data = data {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
         //Do something with data
         }
      }

}
```

I think closures is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are 3 main ways to do this. The idea is you want to send off a call to a class, in this case, for networking, and have it come back sometime later and do something.

Delegates+Protocols are fantastic for this:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

As are Blocks

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

The other popular way is KVO but that is not ideal for your example.

Comment: I know those structures, can you suggest me something in swift and not in objc?

Comment: I can't find something with an example with blocks that pass data between classes... (in swift)

Answer (score 1):

I will use closure in swift,

For example

```
class Service{
        func requestDocuments(completion:(response:AnyObject)->()){
            //After network is done
            completion(response:data)
        }
    }
```

Then here to use

```
    service.requestDocuments { (response) -> () in
        //Here you can get response async
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Delegate its the best approach.
Please see below example where delegation approach is demostrated

[AFNetworking 2.0 - How to pass response to another class on success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044970/afnetworking-2-0-how-to-pass-response-to-another-class-on-success)

Another approach would be NSNotification